# Symfony display datepicker when i use jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, datepicker, calendar

Hi everyone i need your help.

I put dates in Jquery in my form with the id:
twig :

```
{{ form_label(Form.date, 'Date') }}
    {{ form_widget(Form.date, {'id': 'datejquery', 'attr': {'class' :'form-control'}}) }}
```

formType :

```
$builder->add('date', DateType::class, ['label' => 'Date', 'widget' => 'single_text', 'html5' => false, 'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy']);
```

The code works with `'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy'`
But the display of the datepicker no longer works when I click on the form fields.

I just have the date that appears in the input but I don't have the calendar display...

When : `{'class' :'js-datepicker'}})`

**display empty calendar**

[image]

Comment: What datepicker are you using for the field?

Comment: I use the basic one from symfony with  'widget' => 'single_text'

I would like to continue using this one without  add another one like bootstrap..

Comment: I was talking about the javascript datepicker. The `single_text` widget renders the field as `type="text"` and you have also disabled the html5 calendar with `html5 => fale`, so you will need to have a javascript which attaches the calendar/datepicker to that field. :)

Comment: I have the $('.js-datepicker').datepicker();
I remplace  'attr': {'class' :'form-control'} with  'attr': {'class' :'js-datepicker'}